# How to convert bulk collect and forall in its equivalent for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have code like the following that needs to be converted to Oracle. It is basically the code to select from a table all or most of its data, put that into a collection and then load it into another table, using BULK COLLECT and FORALL. I will be thankful for help. Following is the oracle code that needs to be migrated into postgresql.

```
SQL> desc t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                              NUMBER(38)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(4)

SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                              NUMBER(38)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(4)

SQL> select * from t;

     EMPNO ENAM
---------- ----
         1 a
         4 d
         3 c
         2 b
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_n_bulk_load
IS
   TYPE v_t IS TABLE OF t%ROWTYPE;

   v1_t   v_t;
BEGIN
   SELECT t.*
     BULK COLLECT INTO v1_t
     FROM t;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (TO_CHAR (v1_t.COUNT));

   FORALL i IN 1 .. v1_t.COUNT
      INSERT INTO T1 (EMPNO, ENAME)
           VALUES (V1_T (i).empno, v1_t (i).ename);

   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct translation would be to use an array of the table's type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function temp_n_bulk_load()
 returns void
as
$$
declare
   v_t t[]; -- t is the table name and at the same time a data type
   l_count bigint;
BEGIN
   SELECT array_agg(t)
     into v_t
   FROM t;

   l_count := cardinality(v_t);
   raise notice 'Retrieved % rows', l_count;

   INSERT INTO T1 (EMPNO, ENAME)
   select r.*
   from unnest(v_t) as r;

   -- you can't COMMIT in a function
END;
language plpgsql;
```

---

But the whole approach is unnecessary complicated and will not scale - that is also true for the Oracle solution. Using a single `insert into .. select` is **way** more efficient - in Postgres just as well as in Oracle.

The whole procedure should be replaced with:

```
insert into t1 (empno, ename)
select empno, ename
from t1;
```

If you want, you can put that into a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function temp_n_bulk_load()     
   returns void
as $$
  insert into t1 (empno, ename)
  select empno, ename
  from t1;
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: there is one change that I am not selecting all data from the table but rather one column is a parameter defined in the procedure , in that case how would this change. I will post a seperate question for it.

Comment: Actually I wont as I am getting a warning that the question is not well received. I will edit it here in the question itself. please see if possible.

Comment: @dbusern: please do not change your question once you get have answer.

Comment: Ok, I have removed my update so the question is as it was. I will just try it out on my own. thanks.